# Error in displaying image in HTML file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

In my MVC2 application I use CKEditor where I allow the user to create a PDF document.
First the CKEditor content will get converted into HTML file and later as PDF document.
I have provided a button called Arrow on click of it image of an arrow should get inserted. In editor image gets displayed successfully but in HTML and PDF file image is not getting displayed inplace of it alt content gets displayed.

Code for an arrow button:

```
<input type="button" class="green_button" id="arrow" name="Arrow" value="Arrow" style="width: 110px; height: 30px; background-color: #FFFFFF;" onclick="return arrow_onclick()" />

function arrow_onclick() {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.message;
    editor.insertHtml(' <input type="image" alt="arrow" src="../../PDFimages/arrow-left-up.jpg" style="height:100px; width:100px" />');
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult CreateFile(FormCollection data)
    {
        var filename = data["filename"];
        var htmlContent = data["content"];
        string sFilePath = Server.MapPath(_createdPDF + filename + ".html");
        htmlContent = htmlContent.Trim();
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(sFilePath))
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    w.Write(htmlContent);
                }
            }
            string filename1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFilePath);
            string name = Server.MapPath(_createdPDF + filename1 + ".pdf");
            HTML2PDF.SetModulePath(@"C:\Documents and Settings\shubham\My Documents\visdatemplatemanger\visdatemplatemanger\bin");
            using (PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc())
            {
                if (HTML2PDF.Convert(doc, sFilePath))

                    doc.Save(name, pdftron.SDF.SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
            }
            System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath);
            UploadURL(name);
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before submit your form, you should set textarea value from CkEditor and make your action that accepts the post has this annotation applied `[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]`

```
$("#content").val(CKEDITOR.instances.message.getData());
```

And check your src value. Maybe should using:

```
src="@(Url.Content( "~/PDFimages/arrow-left-up.jpg" ))"
```

if `PDFimages` folder included in `Project/Content`